# Should I refer to an instance or a class method in a loop that creates objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, design-patterns, methods, import-csv

I am working on importing a .csv file into a Ruby on Rails app. The importer will create a new database record from each row of the file.

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord

  def self.import(file)
    output_log = []
    CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
      output_log << some_method_name(row)
    end
    return output_log
  end

end
```

I want all the complexity of data validation, record creation, and error reporting to be tucked away in another method, rather than cluttering up my `import` method. I'm calling `some_method_name` as an example. What should I really be calling?

Two possibilities occur to me. An instance method:

```
output_log << Invoice.new.populate_from_row(row)
```

Or, a class method:

```
output_log << Invoice.create_from_row(row)
```

(Either would return a string that logs success or failure.)

Both will work, but which makes more sense? Is there some design principle or pattern that should inform me about how to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the most adequate method name inside your `import` method and encapsulate all the logic inside a private method (or a service object). In my applications I usually do something like the following:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord

  def self.import(file)
    output_log = []
    CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
      output_log << create_invoice_from_csv_row(row)
    end
    return output_log
  end

  private

  def create_invoice_from_csv_row(row)
    Invoice.find_or_create_by(
      order_number: row["Order Number"],
      customer_name: row["Customer Name"],
      # ...
    )
    return ""
  rescue => e
    return e.message
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks good! You've chosen a class method; any insight into why you made that choice? Does it really matter?

Comment: Will you be using this code somewhere else? If yes, I'd probably opt for a ServiceObject so you can reuse the code without duplicating it.